# How many one to one functions f: A→A have at least one fixed point?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

Let $A = \{1,2,3, ..., 7\}$.
A function $f: A → A$ is said to have a
fixed point if for some $x \in A$, $f(x) = x$. How many one-
to-one functions $f: A → A$ have at least one fixed point?

This is a derangement question.

My answer is $7! - D7$ for at least one fixed point.

But I am confused with the approach for at least $2$ fixed points.
If I choose $2$ fixed out of $7$ it is $7C2$ then remaning can deranged in $D5$.

So it is $7! -7C2\times D5$. Is the answer right?

Comment: You might want to google " telephone numbers "

Comment: You can count directly or you can count how many have no fixed points and subtract that from the total number of injective functions. If the full problem is too big start with smaller sets for $A$ and try to see what happens when you add another element.

Comment: You'd be excluding those with 3 or more fixed points.

Comment: see [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  Then re-read the comment of @CyclotomicField.

Comment: Oh I got it, _`7! - ( D7+ 7C1*D6 )`_ , here I am including all permutations and subtracting them with at least one fixed point and no fixed Point. Is it right now? @CalvinLin

Comment: @VedantKhandelwal Yup.